# Asp.net application Having session Issues in only Some old Versions browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-chrome, c#-4.0, google-chrome-app

When We Load the asp.net application in old version Browser it's shows the below Session error(EX: Chrome Version 56) but the latest browser the Application works fine. How to resolve this Issue?

[image]

> Error: (Please Check The Image).
> **Server Error in '/' Application.**
> Specified Cast is not Valid

```
InDate = (DateTime)Session["CheckIn"];
```